# Calling DB2 stored procedure from Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, db2

I am trying to call DB2 Stored procedure from entity framework.  I have created Store schema and conceptual schema based on the SP. I have specified an Entity as a return type  to get the data back from SP call. At design time, i am getting the below message as warning

Warning 1   Error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer DB2Container12345.

At runtime I am getting the below error..

Runtime Error : 
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Data.DB2.msl(6,6) : error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer DB2Container12345.

Any help would be appreciated. I am almost stuck up with this point...

Thanks,
Ganesan Subbian

Comment: I think you need to post your edmx (or csdl, msl, and ssdl) files. Ideally they would contain only data relevant to the repro. Alternatively create a new model that contains just one entity with just a few properties and a mapping similar to what you are trying to achieve. This would should give a starting point for resolving your problem.